# Looking for a better word in the sentence

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, clauses

```
 "We encourage our employees to keep flexible hours and don't require them to track their time."
```

I think that the word 'require' is misplaced here.
It can probably be replaced by 'ask'.

Can I add any better word here?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it as worded. If anything I find the earlier part of the sentence more confusing.

Comment: That can be made simpler... "We offer flexible work hours..."

Comment: Then I would say *We offer flexible work hours and don't require employees to track and report their time*

Comment: @user1414696, could you explain why `require` would be misplaced? Is it the meaning of `require` what you find out of place? If so, could you explain why?

Comment: Probably because, I have rarely seen "require" being used in Simple Present Tense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, my answer would be that "require" is not misplaced here and that I can't think of a better word to indicate that the company has no policy that requires workers to track their time.